# sorted() function in python when reading a file sorts numbers by 1st digit only. I'm trying to print a high scores list in a python game

Tags: python, sorting

The code works as long as the numbers don't contain 0's. Otherwise it sorts like 9 is higher than 10 for example.

```
def enter_high_score():
    print()
    name=input("Please Enter You Name: ")
    file=open("score.txt", "a")
    file.write(str(9000) +"\t" +(name)+ "\n")
    
    
    file.close()

    file=open("score.txt", "r")
    readthefile = file.readlines()
    sorted_scores = sorted(readthefile,reverse=True)

    print("Top 5 Scores!")
    print("Pos\tPoints\tName")

    for line in range(5):
        # print(str(sortedData[line])+"\t"+str(line+1))
        print(str(line+1)+"\t"+str(sorted_scores[line]))
```

Comment: the text file is just this;
9 S.M.Gimp
9 T.Moore
10 Rob Kirk
10 G. A. R.
10 R Grimes
9000 Jim

Comment: If you need to add more info to your question don't put it in the comments. You can update your question.

Comment: it is sorting by 1st digit..? because data type of there is `string` if you can change to `int` than sorting will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Vahid is right with their answer, but there's no need to seperate that digit out and create a list of tuples to sort based on the first word in the line as an integer. We can just extract that info directly in the call to `sorted`.

```
>>> data = """15 hello
... 9 world
... 3 foo bar"""
>>> lines = data.split('\n')
>>> sorted(lines, key=lambda line: int(line.split(' ', 1)[0]))
['3 foo bar', '9 world', '15 hello']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
name = input("Please Enter You Name: ")
# note that you are appending to the file and at line 5 writing same score every time
file = open("score.txt", "a")
# use Python f-string
file.write(f"9000\t{name}\n")
file.close()
 
file = open("score.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
# For each line create a list of tuples of (int, str), e.g. [(200,John)]
records = list(map(lambda line: (int(line.split()[0]), line.split()[1]), lines))

# Highest first, key is saying sort based on first item in (int, str) which is the score
sorted_records = sorted(records, key=lambda r: r[0], reverse=True)
print(sorted_records)
```

Comment: Please don't include line numbers in code.

Comment: Line numbers help us refer to different parts of code. If not used one should unnecessarily put the whole code that is being referred to. People have different opinion about it but I think its very useful like this   [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346234/2659499). I hope that SO implement it!

Comment: An important reason not to include the line numbers is that they makes it impossible for anyone to copy and paste your code and have it immediately work. Every single person who wants to run your code will need to manually edit out every line number. It's generally easy enough to refer to lines by their contents (e.g. "the map() line" or "the file.write() line") that exact line numbers are not ncessary.

Comment: @Blckknght, yes, u are right. It makes it hard for others to copy and test. Its going to work if SO adds this feature to the site. I'll remove the numbers

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a work around as I'm not quite up to the level as mentioned above.
So basically, I've created some if statements saying that;
if number is within a certain range say 999 - 1000 for example add "00" to the front.

So my scores read 00100
00010
00001
for example... and if it's over any of those specified values there's an else statement goin "woah you scored off the charts your so good!"